# New 5.0.x UsageStats reset periodically

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop

So we set out to gather usage statistics hourly, asking for the last hour using the Interval_Daily

```
queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, startTime, timeNow);
```

where `timeNow` is incremented at each hour and is always one hour ahead.

Issues:

1. when user goes to sleep in the night, queryStats are null. This is not so bad since the user does nothing
2. more importantly, the Usagestats reset sometimes:

From

```
[{"start_time":"2015-01-14T13:12:00.154-0800"},
{"app_package":"com.hipchat","app_time_in_foreground":886341,"app_launches":5}
```

to

```
[{"start_time":"2015-01-14T14:11:49.814-0800"},
{"app_package":"com.hipchat","app_time_in_foreground":48851,"app_launches":3}
```

3. Usage Stats are cumulative until they reset

```
[{"start_time":"2015-01-14T09:12:00.242-0800"},
{"app_package":"com.hipchat","app_time_in_foreground":230317,"app_launches":11}

[{"start_time":"2015-01-14T10:11:37.839-0800"},
{"app_package":"com.hipchat","app_time_in_foreground":712018,"app_launches":24}

[{"start_time":"2015-01-14T11:11:50.694-0800"},
{"app_package":"com.hipchat","app_time_in_foreground":792177,"app_launches":6}

[{"start_time":"2015-01-14T12:11:49.643-0800"},
{"app_package":"com.hipchat","app_time_in_foreground":815998,"app_launches":3}

[{"start_time":"2015-01-14T13:12:00.154-0800"},
{"app_package":"com.hipchat","app_time_in_foreground":886341,"app_launches":5}
```

However, it would seem that UsageEvents are not cumulative, from looking at the "app_launches"

Can someone clarify all?